# C# how to serialize JSON array of objects and convert object name to property value

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

I have a JSON string which has an array of objects.  I need to serialize into a .NET class and use the object name as a property value.

```
public class DocumentFieldMap
    
{
        
    [Key]
        
    [JsonPropertyName("letterCode")]
        
    public string DocumentCode { get; set; }
        
    [JsonPropertyName("letterFields")]
        
    public List<DocumentField> DocumentFields { get; set; }
    
}

    
public class DocumentField
    
{
        
    [Key]
        
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
        
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
        
    public string ReadOnly { get; set; }
    
}
```

```
[
  {
    "letterCode": "RR",
    "letterFields": {
      "Name": {
        "DataSource": "",
        "ReadOnly": "true"
      },
      "Signature": {
        "DataSource": "",
        "ReadOnly": "false"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to serialize the letterFields object name (ex. Name) as the FieldName property and I cannot find a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to transform it to another class which will contain `Dictionary<string, ...>` (convention for (de)serializing dictionaries as object is supported by some JSON libraries, especially two "main" ones in .NET - Newtonsoft's Json.NET and System.Text.Json). For example with anonymous types:

```cs
var maps = new[]
{
    new DocumentFieldMap
    {
        DocumentCode = "code",
        DocumentFields =
        [

            new DocumentField
            {
                FieldName = "Name",
                DataSource = "",
                ReadOnly = "true"
            }
        ]
    }
};

var serialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(maps.Select(m => new
{
    letterCode = m.DocumentCode,
    letterFields = m.DocumentFields
        .ToDictionary(f => f.FieldName, 
            field => new { field.DataSource, field.ReadOnly }) 
}));
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

Note that `ToDictionary` will throw for duplicate names, so you might need to handle that in case if this is a possibility. Also if you want you can switch from anonymous types to special classes for serialization (DTOs).

Another option would be creating [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) for the type.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Do you have a recommendation on how to do the reverse and Deserialize the JSON back into an object?

Comment: @user15246208 was glad to help! For deserialization, as partially written in the answer you can use the same approach - create corresponding DTO structure (with `Dictionary<string, ....>`) and deserialize to it (it would be the same as for serialization, but you will need to create types since anonymous ones can't be used here, at least elegantly). If needed then map it corresponding destination classes. P.S. feel free to upvote answer also ;)

Comment: To deserialize, I used this class with a Dictionary:  public class DocumentFieldMap
    
{
        
    [Key]
        
    [JsonPropertyName("letterCode")]
        
    public string DocumentCode { get; set; }
        
    [JsonPropertyName("letterFields")]
        
    public Dictionary<string, DocumentField> DocumentFields { get; set; }
    
}